# Nunit is not running in any test method

Tags: c#, nunit

I have two classes in class library

```
namespace ClassLibrary3
{
public class Class1
{
    public string title;
    public string author;
    public Class1(string title, string author)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
}
```

Another class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary3
```

{
    class Class2
    {
        private Hashtable books;

```
    public Class2()
    {
        books = new Hashtable();
    }

    public void addBook(Class1 book)
    {
        books.Add(book.title, book);
    }

    public Class1 getBook(String title, String author)
    {
        return (Class1)books[title];
    }

    public void removeBook(string title)
    {
        if (books[title] != null)
            books.Remove(title);
    }


}
}
```

And my test is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections;
namespace ClassLibrary3
{
[TestFixture]
class TEST
{
    [Test]
    public void getbooktest()
    {
    Class1 c1 = new Class1("story", "James");
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();

   Assert.AreEqual("story", c2.getBook("story", "James"));

    }
}
}
```

Basicly the problem is Nunit doesnt test it. It finds the dll. Loads the test class. But dont come upto the test method.
Please any idea..........

Comment: Thanks. I got it. The problem was - In a stupid attempt, i gave the name of class "TEST". Which is a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit can't see your TEST class unless you mark it as public, change it to

```
[TestFixture]
public class TEST
{
   ...
```

Side note, consider giving it a better name than TEST ;-)

Comment: TEST is seen by NUNIT. But problem is its not accessing getbooktest().